# Table to be filled automatically in ax 2009

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I have a form with HeaderTable and LineTable datasource. HeaderTable contains FromDate and ToDate field and LineTable contains TransactionDate field.

As per the requirement I have to fill the TransactionDate field with 'fromdate' TO 'todate'.

For Example, if HeaderTable contains 1st-Jan & 8th-Jan as fromdate and todate respectively , than in line level it should automatically creates records for 1st to 8th Jan.

I hope it can be done using a button, but not clear. Please suggest with examples.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Jan for replying.

This is how I solved this problem:

I created a button, on clicked method of the button I wrote this logic:

```
FromDate = Header.FromDate;

while (FromDate <= Header.ToDate)
{
    Line.InvoiceId = Header.InvoiceId;
    Line.TransactionDate = FromDate;
    Line.doInsert();
    FromDate++;

    if (FromDate == Line.TransactionDate)
    {
        break;
    }

}

Line_ds.research(true);

}
```

Hope this will help someone. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing happens automatically, do it your self:

```
for (transDate = fromDate; transDate <= toDate; transDate++)
{
    salesLine.clear()
    salesline.TransDate = transDate;
    salesLine.initFrom...
    salesLine.createLine(...);
}
```

I am glad I do not have to code the update logic, when the user changes the `fromDate` or `toDate`!

Comment: Hi Jan, yes nothing happens automatically, my problem is solved. :)

Thanks.. :)